# When asking about a health condition which tense do you use?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense, writing

If a person got injured, in their legs, for example, yesterday and you want to ask that person the next day how are their legs doing. Do you say "how were your legs?" or "how are your legs?" and why?

Answer (score 2):

The answer has nothing to do with whether you're asking about a health condition.

If you want to ask how they are now, use the present tense:

> How are your legs?

If you want to ask about how they were yesterday, use the past tense:

> How were your legs [after the accident]?